# how to paginate ordering by non-distinct / non-unique values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pagination

How can I properly page by ordering on a column that could possibly have repeated values? I have a table called `posts`, which has a column that holds the number of likes of a certain post, called `num_likes`, and I want to order by `num_likes DESC`. But the image below shows a problem that I run into - the new row inserted between the two pages causes repeated data to be fetched.

[This link here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) explains the problem, and gives the solution of *keyset pagination*, but from what I've seen, that only works if the column that the rows are being sorted on are **distinct / unique**. How would I do this if that is not the case?

[image: new row problem pagination]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily make the sort key unique by adding the primary key to it.

You don't have to display the primary key to the user, just use it internally to tell “equal” rows apart.

For querying and indexing, you can make use of PostgreSQL's ability to compare like this: `(num_likes, id) >= (4, 325698)`.

Comment: Wow thanks! I never knew that was a things. But if I assign auto-incrementing primary keys when the posts are created, and I order by `num_likes`, how would the primary keys be in ascending order still? I feel like they won’t.

Comment: They don't have to be! If you `ORDER BY num_likes, id`, the rows are first sorted by `num_likes`, and only for equal `num_likes`, the rows are sorted by `id`. It won't change the visible ordering, but still make the rows unique so you don't get the same row twice.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just found this post and I believe it solves my issue with non-unique columns. My concern here is the performance, do you consider it is worth it to add a pre calculated column with those concatenated values or is the execution time good? I saw some articles mentioning you can concatenate on the fly on the where but that makes the query really slow. I assume this is different because of the index? Thanks!

Comment: @sfratini There is no benefit in concatenating columns, let alone in storing those concatenated values redundantly in the table.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But it seems to have odd behaviors when one of the value is NULL. It will skip a couple rows before resuming pagination properly. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Guillaume There shouldn't be anything odd about that. Perhaps ask a new question that details on your problem.